# Obtener IMEI en Android sin solicitar permisos

Tags: android

Tengo una app en la que identifo a cada dispositivo mediante el número `IMEI`,

El problema es que para solicitar este número, androiod muestra una ventana al usuario indicando que si le concedo permisos para acceder a las llamadas y al estado del teléfono. **Por lo que muchos usuarios dicen que no**

Esto es un problema ya que sin ese código no me es posible identifar los dispositivos ni asociar un dispositivo con un usuario.

Hay alguna forma de solicitar el imei sin permisos? o de solicitar otro código unico de dispositivo?

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
   public void getImeiFunc() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
    else {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            imei = telephonyManager.getImei(0);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(0);
            } else {
                imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html - Puedes informar al usuario de que necesitas el número IMEI de su móvil para identificar el dispositivo, siempre en aras de mejorar el funcionamiento de la app y bla bla bla... y después intentas leer el IMEI y posiblemente te lo acepten. Si aun así no lo aceptan (yo no lo haría), plantéate si de verdad necesitas saber el IMEI para el correcto funcionamiento de tu app. ¡A no ser que quieras sacarle el IMEI a la gente sin que se entere, en plan NSA!

Comment: @jotaelesalinas lo que comentas considero es la mejor solución, indicarle previamente al usuario que le sugieres aceptar los permisos para un correcto funcionamiento de la aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes recordar que para dispositivos con OS 6.0 o mayor es necesario requerir manualmente algunos [permisos que son considerados "peligrosos",](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) entre estos permisos se encuentra el permiso: [READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE).

Una forma para evitar el requerir permisos es definir un [targetSdkVersion menor a 23](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html), pero en un futuro tu aplicación requerirá de actualizar las Libraries a sus mas recientes versiones y por ende tendrás que definir un targetSdkVersion mayor.

Es muy importante definir que **no se puede evitar la petición de estos permisos, si lo haces simplemente tu aplicación no funcionará correctamente**. Una forma que **te recomiendo es abrir un diálogo antes de la petición de permisos para sugerirle al usuario aceptar los siguientes permisos con el objetivo de que su aplicación funcione correctamente.**

---

Este es un método para obtener el IMEI de un dispositivo en todas las versiones de sistema operativo:

```
  public String obtenerImei(){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            //Menores a Android 6.0
            String imei= getIMEI();
            return imei;
        } else {
            // Mayores a Android 6.0
            String imei="";
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                imei="";
            } else {
                imei= getIMEI();
            }

            return imei;

        }
    }

    private String getIMEI() {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei =tm.getDeviceId(); 
        return imei;

    }
```

Comment: mmm -1 ? ¿Alguna razón por el voto negativo? Seria buena idea para mejorar mis respuestas.