# No recoge el número de teléfono

Tags: android

estoy intentado guardar el numero de teléfono en la variable String telefono de mi clase Persona

```
public class Persona {

    String telefono;
    public Persona(String tlf) {
        this.telefono = tlf;
    }
    public Persona()
    {
        this.telefono = "";

    }

    public void setTelefono (String tlf) { this.telefono = tlf;}
    public String getTelefono (){return telefono; }
}
```

Esta es la clase de la activty:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_planes);

        json="";
        Persona per = new Persona();

        per.setTelefono(getPhoneNumber());
        Log.i("DEBUG",per.getTelefono());

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        json = gson.toJson(per);

        Log.i("DEBUG",json);
        peticionAsync();

    }

    private String getPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return mTelephonyManager.getLine1Number();
    }
```

y este es el log:

> 11-22 17:34:56.657 23495-23495/arwa I/DEBUG:
>   {"telefono":""}

Como veis el primer Log.i no le muestra, muestra el segundo que es el que saca el json.

En la clase persona me dice esto en los métodos set and get:

> Spellchecker inspection helps locate typos and misspelling in your
>   code, comments and literals, and fix them in one click

Y no entiendo cual es el error.

¿Alguien sabe por qué es ? 
En otra clase pido el numero de telefono y si lo recoge,he copiado la funcion getPhoneNumber, por tanto no es problema de permisos en el manifiest

Muchas gracias!

Comment: he probado tu codigo y funciona bien, que version de android usas? puede que sea cuestion de permisos

Comment: Es un problema de que el telefono es dualSIM, he cambiado la tarjeta de ranura y ya funciona, no entiendo muy bien por qué una ranura si y otra no, pero si funciona no lo toques :)

Answer (score 2):

Es importante revises la documentación relacionada a [getLine1Number()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getLine1Number()):

> [getLine1Number()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getLine1Number()) Devuelve la cadena de número de teléfono para la
>   línea 1, por ejemplo, el MSISDN para un teléfono GSM. Devuelve nulo si
>   no está disponible.

**Por lo tanto debes estar consciente que existe la posibilidad de no retornar el numero telefónico.**

---

Estas pueden ser las causas de no obtener el número telefónico :

- Tu numero debe estar registrado en el teléfono, ve a

`Settings` -> `About Phone` -> `Status` -> `My phone Number`

el número también se puede encontrar en `SIM Status`.

Si no se encuentra, esta puede ser la causa.

---

- Si esta disponible el número pero no obtienes valor, debes asegurar que para android versión 6.0 o posterior debes requerir los permisos [READ_PHONE_STATE, READ_SMS, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE) manualmente.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de como requerir el permiso [READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE)

[Obtener IMEI en Android sin solicitar permisos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121116/obtener-imei-en-android-sin-solicitar-permisos?rq=1)